# Фон в приложении

Tags: android, интерфейс

Как в сделать так, чтобы при изменении значения seekbar менялся фон окна(фон окна задан картинками).

Comment: В этом вам может помочь AsincTasc, потому что он работает в фоновом режиме

Comment: @Alex, AsyncTask работает не на главном потоке, да. Но ТС хочет сменить картинку на экране, т.е. эти вещи точно не связаны.

Answer (score 1):

*Ответ дан с использованием языка Kotlin*

Есть сик бар, предположим что у него диапазон 0-4, то есть мы можем установить его в 5-ть разных позиций, берём наши 5ть картинок кладём их в папочку drawable, и делаем с нашим сикбаром следующее:

```
seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(object : SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {
            override fun onProgressChanged(seekBar: SeekBar?, progress: Int, fromUser: Boolean) {
                if (fromUser) {
                    when (progress) {
                        0 -> yourView.background = resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.img_0)
                        1 -> yourView.background = resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.img_1)
                        2 -> yourView.background = resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.img_2)
                        3 -> yourView.background = resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.img_3)
                        4 -> yourView.background = resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.img_4)
                    }
                }
            }

            override fun onStartTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar?) {
            }

            override fun onStopTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar?) {
            }

        })
```